# Synchronizing multiple (Highcharts) on a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have multiple highcharts on a page, which could have different series. If somebody hovers over a chart, I want this hover to be synced on other charts as well (showing the tooltip at the hovered X-point, showing hover effect etc).

When I use this example to try to sync multiple charts https://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts

I'm failing because my charts do NOT live in the same div. Their example however does only work if the charts are below each other, not if they are placed next to each other or anywhere at the page.

Ideally, I would just sync the value of the hovered x Axis point as this value (timestamp) is the same for all charts available on this page.

Anybody knows a non hacky way how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In broad strokes the way I have solved this in the past would be to use the [`mouseOver`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) event for a point to capture that points xAxis value. See this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-mouseover/). In addition to getting the value, I would call a custom function that goes through all charts and highlight the same xAxis value there (if it exists).

To make this easier I would make some global array or similar that has a reference to all charts on the page. This way you don't need to explicitly reference each chart from other charts. To make this look nice and be practical, all charts need to be able to call the same custom function to highlight a value, and have a similar function that removes the highlight on the `mouseOut` event.

This is just one possible solution, there are many ways to achieve what you are after.

---

Here is a very basic implementation of what I wrote above

```
function sharedMouseOver() {
  let currentX = this.x
  charts = Highcharts.charts;
  charts.forEach(function(chart, index) {
    chart.series.forEach(function(series, seriesIndex) {
      series.points.forEach(function(point, pointsIndex) {
        if (point.x == currentX) {
          point.setState('hover')
        }
      })
    });
  });
}

function sharedMouseOut() {
  charts = Highcharts.charts;
  charts.forEach(function(chart, index) {
    chart.series.forEach(function(series, seriesIndex) {
      series.points.forEach(function(point, pointsIndex) {
          point.setState('')
      });
    });
  });
}
```

And in each chart you can find this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: sharedMouseOver,
        mouseOut: sharedMouseOut
      }
    },
    ...
}
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/tvgL8pnh/17/

```js
function sharedMouseOver() {
  let currentX = this.x
  charts = Highcharts.charts;
  charts.forEach(function(chart, index) {
    chart.series.forEach(function(series, seriesIndex) {
      series.points.forEach(function(point, pointsIndex) {
        if (point.x == currentX) {
          point.setState('hover')
        }
      })
    });
  });
}
function sharedMouseOut() {
  charts = Highcharts.charts;
  charts.forEach(function(chart, index) {
    //if (chart.renderTo.id === chartsId) {
    //    chosenChart = chart;
    //}
    chart.series.forEach(function(series, seriesIndex) {
      series.points.forEach(function(point, pointsIndex) {
          point.setState('')
      });
    });
  });
}


Highcharts.chart('container', {
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: sharedMouseOver,
          mouseOut: sharedMouseOut
        }
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [43934, 52503, 57177, 69658, 97031, 119931, 137133, 154175]
  }, {
    name: 'Other',
    data: [12908, 5948, 8105, 11248, 8989, 11816, 18274, 18111]
  }],


});
Highcharts.chart('container2', {
  legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      point: {
        events: {
          mouseOver: sharedMouseOver,
          mouseOut: sharedMouseOut
        }
      },
      pointStart: 2010
    }
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Manufacturing',
    data: [24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434]
  }],


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<div id="container2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi. thanks,
the example link throws a "not allowed" page for me. I'm actually looking for examples how to highlight the same point on the xAxis as I can't find any. The syncing part (like sending the x points through the system) is super easy and already done. I'm just struggling to build such a "shared function to highlight the same point"